# Reading in words of a sentence one by one in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to read in the words of a sentence entered by the user one by one, by putting each word into an array, however I could not come up with a good solution.

I have tried:

```
    printf("Enter your sentence: ");

    while(scanf("%s", word) != EOF)
    {
       wordArray[i] = word;
       i ++;
    }
```

where ***wordArray*** is a string array, ***i*** is an integer and ***word*** is a string.

I would have liked this to read each word of a sentence and put it in the array.

For example, if I entered "I am Mark", I would have liked this snippet of code to put:

`"I" in wordArray[0]`

`"am" in wordArray[1]`

`"Mark" in wordArray[2]`

However, this method doesn't work, so could anyone **please give me a method to read each word of the sentence one by one?**

Comment: "However, this method doesn't work " What *does* this method do?? Compile? Run? Have unexpected results? "where wordArray is a string array" *Show that declaration*. If `wordArray` is an array of `char*` then this method doesn't work because the same buffer is being used for each word. And all your array is being populated with is the same address of the same buffer in each slot.

Comment: Seriously. Squelch the spam of wild-ass guesses and provide more explanation of what you're seeing. Compiler errors? Runtime errors? Unexpected output? And **show your declaration of `wordArray`**.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot copy strings like this in C. To copy a string from one char array to another, you must use [`strcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy).

You must pay attention though, that the char arrays are large enough for the words entered, therefore the declaration might look

```
char word[256];
char wordArray[10][256];
```

And to prevent buffer overruns, you should check for the index `i` as well as give a maximum field length to [`scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

```
while(i < 10 && scanf("%255s", word) != EOF)
{
   strcpy(wordArray[i], word);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it appears that there is a segmentation fault.  Any idea why?

Comment: You haven't shown your complete code, so I cannot say for sure. But see updated answer.

Comment: You should also use something like `while (i<10 && scanf("%255s", word) != EOF)` so that it doesn't cause any buffer overflows.

Comment: @codebeard Thank you for this hint, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't use assignment operator to assign a string to another string as like others data type such int, float. You should use strcpy() library function which needs 
string.h header file. You code should be:

```
printf("Enter your sentence: ");

    while(scanf("%s", word) != EOF)
    {
       strcpy(wordArray[i],word);
       i ++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it appears that there is a segmentation fault.  Any idea why?

Comment: Have you initialized i outside while() ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `wordArray` as an array of `n`, say, pointers to `char`, and allocate memory for each of them. Say, 20 bytes for each:

```
char word[20];   
int n = 10;
char *wordArray[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    wordArray[i] = malloc(20);
```

and then your code will work.

```
printf("Enter your sentence: ");
int i = 0;
while(scanf("%s", word) != EOF && i < n)
{
  strcpy(wordArray[i], word);
}
```

Do not forget to `free` `wordArray` elements.

Comment: The code in question (edit by Samoth looks pointless btw) assigns address of `word`, same value, to all `wordArray` items. Only thing your `malloc` loop accomplishes is leaking memory, when pointers to allocated buffers are lost in the original loop.

Comment: No it is not. Every word in `wordArray` will be same word, the one which is stored to `word` buffer last. The buffers allocated with `malloc` in your answer are not used for anything.

Comment: @haccks what do you mean to do by `wordArray[i] = word;` in your while loop?

Comment: @ajay: I mean this `strcpy(wordArray[i], word);`. But `wordArray[i] = word;` will not work here. :)

Comment: @hyde; You are right. I edited the answer.

Comment: @haccks obviously that that won't work here. That's what I was pointing to. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to make array of strings in C:

```
const char *arr[10];
arr[0] = "hello"
arr[1] = "world"
```

Or, making a 2D array of chars

```
char arr[10][100];
strcpy(arr[0], "hello");
strcpy(arr[1], "world");
```

And it's better to read word by word from input stream, with

```
char temp[100];
scanf("%s", temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<string.h>

    int main()
   {
       char ch,word[20][20];
       static int i,j;
       printf("Enter the sentence: ");
       ch=getchar();
       while( ch != '\n' )
        {
             if (ch == ' ' )
             {
              word[i][j] = '\0';
             i++;
             j=0;
             }
            else
            word[i][j++] = ch;
            ch = getchar();
         }

       for ( j=0;j<i;j++)
       {
        puts(word[j]);
      }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: this is the complete code

Comment: Proper indentation would be good too, especially on code you want others to learn from.

Comment: What about the code..Thanks for telling me..